# Integration of logarithmic function

Tags: calculus, integration

Compute the integration from 1to 4of greatest integer function of log x .  Log1 =0 & log 10 =1 so this integration should be 0. But answer is 4-e .

Comment: Where did you see that "answer is 4- e"?  Your integral is from 0 to 4 not 1 to 4.  What happens between 0 and 1?

Comment: Yeah it's 1 to 4.

Comment: Please, see the [MSE-$\LaTeX$-$\texttt{MathJax}$ Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

The given answer is right if your integrand is the floor of the *natural* logarithm.

Then the integrand is $0$ from $1$ to $e$ and $1$ from $e$ to $4$.

Comment: How can I compute it?

Comment: @User420: this answer gives you enough clue. Plot the function.